# a question about NetworkManager.conf

Tags: networking, configuration

Please forgive me if the question is a newbie question. In NetworkManger.conf, we can define

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

In this case, does it mean networkmanager is disabled for all network adapters/connections? If yes, how do we disable network manager for a specific adapter/connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be disabled for all interfaces in that situation.

You have 2 options to manage individual interface handling.

1. - Temporary - Will reset after reboot.

You can use `nmcli` to disable the specific interface from being managed.

`sudo nmcli dev set wlp2s0 managed no` <-- Remember to change the interface name to your specific one from `wlp2s0`.

2. - Permanent - Will be persistent from boot to boot.

You can edit `NetworkManager.conf` and add the following

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0 <---change this last part after the : to your interface name.
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. how do I define connection name, such as wlp2s0 or vboxnet0, in your example. In my case, I have HWADDR, for example, HWADDR=00:01:02:03:04:05:06.

Comment: Use `unmanaged-devices=mac:` instead of `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:`

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: It works, thanks. Meanwhile, can I use nmcli to do it programmatically?